# How to make a deployment package with nextjs without using zeit

Tags: next.js

I have a project developed with react + next, now I want to deploy it to my host.

I ran `next build` and it creates `.next` folder with this content, I don't understand the content of `server`, `static` and there is no `index.html`

(I would expect to see something like Angular dist output folder)

[image: out put]

In their documentation [here](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-a-nextjs-app), after running `next build` command they used `zeit` to deploy

Comment: Do `next export` after `next build` if your website is static

Comment: @evgenifotia thanks for your answer, mine is react, so it's dynamic.

Comment: @evgenifotia so I found this repo
https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-firebase-hosting